# Is there a weaker structure a category is made out of?

Tags: category-theory, terminology

> (Category). A category $C$ consists of the following components:
>
> • A class $\text{Ob}(C)$; the elements of $\text{Ob}(C)$ are objects of $C$.
>
> • A set $\text{Mor}_C(X, Y)$ for each choice of objects $X, Y ∈ \text{Ob}(C)$; elements of $\text{Mor}_C(X, Y)$ are called morphisms from $X$ to $Y$. (We implicitly assume that morphism sets between different pairs of objects are disjoint.)
>
> • For all objects $X, Y, Z ∈ \text{Ob}(C)$ a composition$ ◦: \text{Mor}_C(Y, Z) × \text{Mor}_C(X, Y) −→ \text{Mor}_C(X, Z) $
>
> $$ (g, f) −→ g ◦ f$$
> of morphisms.
>
> The above data must satisfy two condition:
>
> 1. Composition of morphism is associative
> 2. Existence of identity morphism in the automorphism set of an object.

Suppose I had a class and a set of morphism assigned to that class (similar to first part of category definition), then would there be any name to this structure?

In otherwords, for a group, it is fundamentally made of a set and a binary operation with additional axioms. So, in the category definition if I removed the additional axioms, would I get any meaningful object?

Comment: If you remove those axioms, how many interesting results can you prove?

Comment: Well that I am not sure but I was trying to see if category can be thought to build up from more basic structure like how we say a set builds a magma nad then magma becomes a group @Randall

Comment: You might be interested in semicategories and paracategories.

Comment: There are things called [plots](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Plots-and-Their-Applications-Part-I%3A-Foundations-Tringali/f2eeeb15b23905d703aa41058a79e3dfe45093b6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loosely speaking:

- A category without identities or composites corresponds to a [directed multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph#Directed_multigraph_(edges_with_own_identity)) (in category theory, often called a *quiver*).
- A category without identities corresponds to a [semicategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/semicategory).
- A category with only partial nonassociative composition corresponds to a [neocategory](http://www.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1972__13_2_104_0.pdf).
- A category with only partial composition corresponds to a [paracategory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/paracategory).

Note that not all of this terminology is very common/standard.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're trying to fill in the analogy "magma:group::___:category" - or in other words, you're looking for a standard name for a "partial magma" (= set equipped with a partial binary function). As far as I know this is too weak a notion to have a commonly used name. However, in Bruck's *[A survey of binary systems](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-43119-1)*, the term "**halfgroupoid**" is used, with "groupoid" being used synonymously with "magma" (contra the more current usage).

If I were *really* pressed to use a term to describe this, I would go with "partial magma" - even if uncommon, its meaning is quite clear. If I wanted to connect explicitly with Bruck's book and the various sources cited therein, I might compromise and go with "halfmagma," but I would never use "halfgroupoid" given the ambiguity around the term "groupoid."